# How to design menuitem view with icon and text on action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem

The action mode has a menu with one menuitem which is specialized as follows:

```
menu.add(0,1,1,R.string.kitapliga_ekle)
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.plus_icon)
                    .setShowAsAction(
                            com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS |
                            com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

I wonder if I can swap icon and text. also is margin between them possible?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it would be easier to create a custom layout in XML for your `ActionBar` and then set it using `ActionBar.setCustomView()`.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But when there is such option (icon+text), I wonder if these functionalities are available, since it takes less effort. Otherwise, action mode of android library looks quite nice, no need for custom view. Additionally, design of it can be considered as best-practice for android. So, it would be always sensible to use default one.

Comment: @Shnkc: where have you reached with this ?

Comment: from common usage of default action bar or this tyle (e.g. no text view or any other view in the middle of actionbar)

Comment: so were you able to do it ?

Comment: no, there is no such feature. It wasn't a good idea in any case. Long press on menu item shows a toast. It is a well-known speciality for android users. So, I decided that this is quite sufficient for an explanation.

Comment: It is a recommendation. I know when to accept an answer! Thanks for reminding.